# WooCommerce: How to hide a custom field in the add new product page for non admins

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce

I am using the WooCommerce Cost of Goods (Cog's) plugin which add an extra filed to my add new products page so that I may enter the cost of each product so that it is reflected in a profit report. The problem is that I need to have non-admins be able to add products but I do not want them to be able to see the cost of goods fields. The solution would be to hide this field completely from non-admin.  Is there a way to do this with a filter or any other way?

You can see screen shots below of where this field is added and the field classes.

```
.form-field _wc_cog_cost_field
```

[Click to see image 1](https://postimg.org/image/lf18z5871/)

[Click to see image 2](https://postimg.org/image/o0xqrq0nr/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use *[admin_head](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_head)* hook to add some css to wp admin.

```
<?php
add_action( 'admin_head', 'my_admin_css');
function my_admin_css() {
$user = wp_get_current_user();

if ( $user->roles[0] != 'administrator' ):
?>
    <style type="text/css">
    .form-field._wc_cog_cost_field {
            display: none !important;
    }
    </style>
<?php
endif;
}//end function
```